# PHP get directory of included file on Virtualhost

Tags: php, url, include, server

I wanna use `__DIR__` on my apache virtual server, but it uses system adress (`C:\xampp\htdocs\virtual\file.php`), is there any way to use server's adress (`/file.php` or `http://virtual/file.php`)?

Thank you for your help

**EDIT:**

Thank you for your answers, but I wanna to include `file.php` elsewhere, so I can't use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Is there another way?

Comment: `__DIR__` has nothing to do with Apache virtual hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__DIR__` will give you the filesystem path of the folder of the file it is used in. Filesystem location and URL can be, depending on your HTTP server configuration, completely unrelated.

You may use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` if you want info about the requested address by the client.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use
 `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`
not 
 `__DIR__`

Answer (score 1):

check this link [enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

**__DIR__** The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to **dirname(__FILE__)**. This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory.

so you must use **dirname(__FILE__)**

Answer (score 0):

`__DIR__` gives you the full absolute file system path. You should use this:

```
dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```